# Do we always have $\chi_{K/Q,x}=\pi_x$ if $K=\mathbb Q(x)$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

If $K=\mathbb Q(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb C$.
Do we always have $\chi_{K/Q,x}=\pi_x$ the minimal polynomial of $x$?

I am using the following definition: $\chi_{K/Q,x}$ is the characteristic polynomial of the application $a\mapsto ax$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Let $\pi_{x}=T^{n}+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}$ be the minimal polynomial of $x\in \mathbb{C}$.
A basis of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ can be chosen as $1,x,x^{2},\cdots,x^{n-1}$.
Now we consider the matrix form of the map $a\mapsto ax$:
\begin{align*}
x\cdot (1,x,\cdots,x^{n-1})=(1,x,\cdots,x^{n-1})
\left(
\begin{matrix}
 & & & -a_{0}\\
1& & & \vdots\\
 &\ddots& &\vdots\\
& &1&-a_{n-1}
\end{matrix}
\right),
\end{align*}
and this is the companion matrix of $\pi_{x}$, thus the character polynomial of the map is $\pi_{x}$.